# Alternating `<Button>` color when hovering another `<Button>`

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have two buttons. The first is a dropdown menu that when hovered, shows two sibling `<a href>`.
The other button is also a sibling, a `formaction` redirect to a different page.

**Problem #1**

I want both bg-color and color of the dropdown menu button to change when hovering one of its `<a href>` .

**Problem #2**

I want both bg-color and color of the dropdown menu button to change when hovering the latter `formaction` button.

I have tried figuring it out with the css below but I can't seem to make it work.

```
.movie-info:hover .dropbtn{
background-color: #A7A774;
color: white;
}
```

my css and html:

```css
.dropbtn {
  width: 210px;
  background-color: #CECE99;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'peninim';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #A7A774;
  color: white;
  min-width: 210px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: peninim;
}

.dropdown-content:hover a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid #767676;
  border-right: 2px solid #212121;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;
  border-left: 2px solid #767676;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #CECE99;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.movie-info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 510px;
  background-color: #A7A774;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'peninim';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.movie-info:hover {
  background-color: #CECE99;
  color: black;
}

.movie-info:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #A7A774;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">dropdown button</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="first.html">first redirect</a>
    <a href="second.html">second redirect</a>
  </div>
</div>


<form target="_blank">
  <button class="movie-info" type="submit" title="redirect" formaction="https://ticks.co.il"> formaction button 
            </button>
</form>
```

Comment: you need JS for it. You can only use the :hover element if you trying to adress a child element. As the Button and the form in your case are sibblings, they cant eb adressed with pure HTML or CSS.

Comment: how do I do it in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, you can do this with JS.

First at all you need to add a `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` trigger to the `dropdown box`.

Then you add a JS that will call the class and change its color and background-color like shown in the snippet:

```js
function hoverTrue() {
  document.querySelector('.dropbtn').style.backgroundColor = "#A7A774";
  document.querySelector('.dropbtn').style.color = "white";
}

function hoverFalse() {
  document.querySelector('.dropbtn').style.backgroundColor = "#CECE99";
  document.querySelector('.dropbtn').style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  width: 210px;
  background-color: #CECE99;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'peninim';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #A7A774;
  color: white;
  min-width: 210px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: peninim;
}

.dropdown-content:hover a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px solid #767676;
  border-right: 2px solid #212121;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;
  border-left: 2px solid #767676;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #CECE99;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.movie-info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 510px;
  background-color: #A7A774;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'peninim';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.movie-info:hover {
  background-color: #CECE99;
  color: black;
}

.movie-info:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #A7A774;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">dropdown button</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="first.html">first redirect</a>
    <a href="second.html">second redirect</a>
  </div>
</div>


<form target="_blank">
  <button class="movie-info" onmouseover="hoverTrue()" onmouseout="hoverFalse()" type="submit" title="redirect" formaction="https://ticks.co.il"> formaction button 
            </button>
</form>
```

Edit for your comment:
like I said, you need to add the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` trigger. Then you give it a function name `functionname()` of your choice followed with bracket open and close.

the javascript needs a function in this formatting:

```js
function functionname() {
  changes
}
```

for the changes you either can adress an ID `document.getElementByID('ID')` or a class `document.querySelector('.class')`. Alternativly youc an use a pre-defined variable.
after that you add a `.style` and a inline style attribute you want to change like color. so the entire line should like this:

document.querySelector('.class').style.color = "red";

If you got all changes you want, you need to close the function with `;}` . Multiple chanegs can be added after a `,` or `;`

Comment: great! thank you. how do I apply this to the dropdown button? in a way that will change its color when hovering the first and the second redirect? many regards in advance!

Comment: I edited the anwser to show you have JS work in this aspect. However it might be worth to read actual basic tutorials abotu JS. Its not so comlicated as it sound first, but espacially doing basic style changes with JS is an efford of maybe 30-60 minutes to learn.